# What is the detriment to storing char data as nvarchar? (And not consistently)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I'm working on a system where we have a number of internally generated reference codes.  These codes can all be represented using a simple, one-bye-per-character set.  Additionally the codes are always of a fixed length.

However, throughout the varying databases and tables, the codes are stored as a mix of `varchar` and `nvarchar`.  How do I find the detrimental costs of this practice?  I can see actual variations in query plans when it is necessary to join from `varchar` to `nvarchar` or vice versa, but don't know how to express this as a business cost.

My question has a number of parts:

- How can I gather some concrete evidence to present to powers-that-be the issues of our current design?
- Are the detriments even so great that I should be concerned in the first place?
- Is there any additional cost introduced by using variable-length character fields for fixed-length data?

  - If so, when does this cost apply?  Only when SQL writes to disk?  On all joins?  Etc?

The simplest example I've put together so far shows the difference in query plans, but of course, since it's so small, the query cost of each is negligible and overall runtime less than a second:

```
declare @Source1 table(Field1 char(4));
insert into @Source1 values ('1234'),('2345');
declare @Source2 table(Field1 varchar(4));
insert into @Source2 values ('1234'),('2345');
declare @Source3 table(Field1 nvarchar(4));
insert into @Source3 values (N'1234'),(N'2345');

declare @Consumer1 table(Field1 char(4), FilterField int);
insert into @Consumer1 values ('1234', 5);
declare @Consumer2 table(Field1 varchar(4), FilterField int);
insert into @Consumer2 values ('1234', 5);
declare @Consumer3 table(Field1 nvarchar(4), FilterField int);
insert into @Consumer3 values (N'1234', 5);

select * from @Consumer1 c inner join @Source1 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer1 c inner join @Source2 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer1 c inner join @Source3 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;

select * from @Consumer2 c inner join @Source1 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer2 c inner join @Source2 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer2 c inner join @Source3 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;

select * from @Consumer3 c inner join @Source1 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer3 c inner join @Source2 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
select * from @Consumer3 c inner join @Source3 s on c.Field1 = s.Field1 where c.FilterField = 5;
```

For additional info, we're using SQL Server 2014 in development and testing and 2008 in the live environment.  I don't expect there to be any differences in this use case, but figured I'd ask if I need to consider something for that, as well?

Comment: You have your database and data, we don't. The only real thing you can do is do a set of performance tests. Do note that you need to make sure to use the correct types everywhere, though - for example `SomeNvarcharField = 'Hi there!'` will not be able to use an index on `SomeNvarcharField`, while `SomeNvarcharField = N'Hi there!'` will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nvarchar` will generally use twice the space as `varchar`.

Exceptions are if you are using page or row compression (in which case you get Unicode compression thrown in) or double byte collations (in which case varchar can take two bytes per character too for some characters).

The main problem will be that `nvarchar` has higher data type precedence than `varchar` so if joining the two the `varchar` side will need to be implicitly cast to `nvarchar` preventing, or at least hindering, index usage on that side.

(It is collation dependant whether or not SQL Server can still manage a [dynamic seek](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx) despite the implicit cast so it might not entirely rule out index usage for a nested loops join but I doubt that you could get a merge join on two indexes of the two different datatypes without an intermediate sort)

Comment: In regards to your first sentence, is the space less a concern on disk and more so for memory?  I'm not a DBA, so don't know specifics, but in general you want to keep row data sizes under 8K, correct?  Should I be concerned about `nvarchar` essentially exceeding that twice as fast as `varchar`?  I'm currently reading through and trying to make further sense of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205318.aspx

Comment: @MikeGuthrie - Mainly for memory though if the table is bloated this does also mean more IOs are needed to read it from disc in the first place. It is difficult to get that excited about the difference between `varchar(4)` and `nvarchar(4)` though as it is only a maximum of 4 bytes per row which is why I focused on the implicit cast.

Comment: The problem is that it's not one `nvarchar(4)` but often around half a dozen.  The most egregious case being 50 `nvarchar(100)` fields referenced against `varchar(100)` values.

Answer (score 1):

one of the more obvious effects is that different datatype prevent the use of foreign key constraints.

drop a few fundamental lines from a parent table while leaving all the child rows untouched and show the result to the boss.

you will get the answer 'nobody would do such a dumb delete' so be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion is the probably the single biggest issue. There are many articles and blog posts discussing the negative performance effects of implicit data conversions.
If the codes are always fixed length and fairly small (e.g. always 4 char) then Char or NChar would be better choices.
The storage space can become an issue when the tables are large.  A char(4) column occupies exactly 4 bytes in the record while a Varchar(4) requires the 4 bytes plus a couple for overhead.  NChar or NVarchar basically double the space requirement.
Codes of this sort are often part of index keys so the space can add up quickly.  They are also frequently referenced in conditional clauses (Where, Order By, Case, etc.) so the Implicit Conversion can also become a major performance issue.
Personally, I would investigate these and try to migrate to the Char datatype and in the root or parent tables and VERY consistent references in code elements.
You should also look at other, similar situations.  For example Char/Varchar to/from Integer is a very common problem.